# SolrServer: is schema required when using addBean( Object bean )?

Tags: solr, solrj

I saw two methods in SolrServer: addBean( Object bean ) and add (SolrDocument doc ).

My question is:

If I can add objects directly using addBean(), do I need to create any schema for the object?
Doesn't Solr look at fields of the object and determine the schema from there?

Or does Solr serialize the object into a string first and then proceeds with a normal add?
(This might require schema specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr supports a *[Schemaless Mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode)*. When starting Solr this way, you are *initially* not bound to a schema. When you give Solr a first document it will guess the appropriate field types and generate a schema that includes those field types for you. These fields are then fixed. You may still add new fields on the fly that way.

This feature is - imho - good for prototyping and to get first version of a schema, but you should not go to production with such a core.

There are some resources out there giving more details on that topic

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode
- http://searchhub.org/2013/05/21/schemaless-solr-part-1/

But to answer your question

1. if you run your server in that schemaless mode, no, you do not need a schema.
2. if you do *not* - which is likely, as it does not come out of the box - yes you do need a schema