# Create schema.xml automatically for Solr from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, solr

Is there an option to generate automatically a schema.xml for solr from mongodb? e.g each field of a document and subdocuments from a collection should by indexed and get searchable by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692954/2160152) Solr's Schemaless Mode could help you

> Solr supports a *[Schemaless Mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode)*. When starting Solr this way, you are *initially* not bound to a schema. When you give Solr a first document it will guess the appropriate field types and generate a schema that includes those field types for you. These fields are then fixed. You may still add new fields on the fly that way.

What you still need to do is to create an Import Route of some kind from your mongodb into Solr.

After googling a bit, you may stumble over the SO question - [solr Data Import Handlers for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345335/solr-data-import-handlers-for-mongodb) - which may help you on that part too.

Probably simpler would be to create a mongo query whose result contains all relevant information you require, save the result to json and send that to Solr's direct update handler, which can parse json.

So in short

1. Create a new, empty core in Schemaless Mode
2. Create an import of some kind that covers all entities and attributes you want
3. Run the import
4. Check if the result is as you want it to be

As long as (4) is not satisfied you may delete the core and repeat these steps.

Answer (score -2):

No, MongoDB does not provide this option. You will have to create a script that maps documents to XML.